# Move contents of subfolders up one level (hundreds of parent folders, all subfolder have the same name)

Tags: windows

Is there a built-in way (WIN7) or third-party utility I can use that will allow me to move the contents of the subfolders of my hundreds of parent folders up one level?

To illustrate:

```
PARENT1/gallery/filex.jpg
PARENT1/gallery/filey.jpg
PARENT1/gallery/filez.jpg
PARENT2/gallery/filex.jpg
PARENT2/gallery/filey.jpg
PARENT2/gallery/filez.jpg
```

What I want to do (at a single batch action, not individual per folder) is:

```
PARENT1/filex.jpg
PARENT1/filey.jpg
PARENT1/filez.jpg
PARENT2/filex.jpg
PARENT2/filey.jpg
PARENT2/filez.jpg
```

Parents have varying names, but all subfolders have the same name "gallery". Is there any quick and painless way to do this? I have roughly 650+ PARENT folders.

Comment: Have you tried renaming tools, eg. [AR](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/)?

Comment: You could take the opportunity to learn Microsoft [PowersHell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd835506(v=vs.85).aspx).  A winner in the Truth In Advertising category!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have Windows execute the same command for all 650 folders sequentially with a simple `for /D` loop. Go to the directory containing the parents and execute the following command:

```
for /D %i in (.\*) do @move %i\gallery\* %i\
```

Optionally, you can delete the empty 'gallery' folders using `rmdir' without the /S-flag, e.g.:

```
for /D %i in (.\*) do @(move %i\gallery\* %i\ && rmdir %i\gallery)
```

For more control over the file operations, you may want to look into `robocopy`, which is far more advanced than `move`. Also note that spaces in directory names are often parsed as delimiters. For example, `rmdir parent 1` will remove the directories 'parent' and '1', but not 'parent 1'. If your directories contain spaces, use quotes, e.g.:

```
for /D %i in (.\*) do @move "%i\gallery\*" "%i\"
```